# Android Native Library - How to match java references to sub_XXX function (static way)

Tags: android, disassemblers

I'm currently learning how native functions are implemented among the ELF SO files contained inside an APK. I'm using IDA.

Native calls are always achieved in this way.

```
// First load the library 
class myClass{
public myClass(){
  super();
  v0 = system.loadLibrary("library-native"); 
  //then declare the methods 
}
public static native int nativeMethod(byte[] arg0, boolean arg1) ;
}
void a(){
  // then uses it 
  ret = this.nativeMethod(byte,bool) ; 
}
```

According to my little experiences in JNI, when looking to library-native.so using a disassembler  I should see something like Java_package_name_libname_class_NativeMethod among the exported function.

I cannot see any of these elements. 
When I'm searching  the desired function (nativeMethod in the past example) inside the disassembled code, I do not find any clue.

I wonder how Dalvik process manages to call the right function when a native call is performed, and how can I find myself the source code of the desired functions ?

Thanks

EDIT : 
I add the nm and readelf output to clarify.

```
nm --defined-only library-native.so 
nm library-native.so : no symbols
readelf -s library-native.so | grep nativeMethod // gives no output
//The only JNI related function 
nm -D --defined-only library-native.so | grep JNI
00XX: JNI_onLoad
```

Comment: if you run `nm` on the file, does  it list the expected symbols?

Comment: Hey Igor, I add the nm and readelf output. Thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the original file does not export the symbols, I can only think of two possibilities:

1. the methods are registered dynamically at load time.
2. (most likely) the file is obfuscated/encrypted and is decrypted on load.

In both cases the action probably happens in the `JNI_onLoad` function. You will need to debug it to see what's going on.

Comment: Could you provide an example (link or quick writing) of method register at load time, I'm not sure to understand what you are talking about and it interest me a lot. Thanks you very much.

Comment: see [`RegisterNatives`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1012427/422797)

Comment: Thanks. Command 
`nm -Du --defined-only native-library.so | grep -i registernative` outputs nothing. 
Same for `readelf -s  native-library.so | grep -i registernative` command. 
Are you agree with me when I conclude that option 2 you pointed is right in this case ?

Comment: `RegisterNatives` is a field (function pointer) in the `JNIEnv` structure (first argument passed to `JNI_onLoad`). You won't see the field names in the binary, just numerical offsets.